# How to make image match height of sibling in row in CSS grid layout

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a layout where I need an image to dynamically match the height of its sibling (a text element) within a row of a CSS Grid layout.

My grid is defined with 10 columns, and the text element spans 8 of these columns, while the image occupies the remaining 2 columns.

I want the grid row's height to be determined by the text element, and the image should adjust its height to fill this row completely. However, when I set the image's height to 100%, the row expands to fit the image instead of the text, which is not the desired behavior.

I’ve tried setting the height of the image to 100%, and the height of the grid to ‘fit-content’, but the row still expands to accommodate the image.

[image]

Here's a simplified version of my current HTML and CSS:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  height: fit-content;
}

.text {
  background: pink;
  grid-column: span 8;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}


.image figure {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

}



.image {
  grid-column-start: 9;
  grid-column: span 2/span 2;
  height: 100%;
}

.image img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <h2>This Section</h2>
    <p>Should set the height of the row</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" alt="Service Image">
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed height: 100% from .image as it's not necessary.
Added display: flex to .image to make it a flex container.
Added flex: 1 to .image figure to make it expand and fill the available space.
Set width: 100% and height: 100% for .image img to make it fill the figure element.